databricks community edition access token not found
I have created a databricks community edition account and free trail azure adf. In ADF notebook activity in databricks linked service how do I connect to the databricks community edition cluster using a access token or what are the other options to run a notebook which is in databricks community edition workspace in adf notebook activity.
Looked for access token in data bricks community edition but couldn't find any

The community version of databricks is just for small POCs or experimentation and learning. Hence the functionality available is limited. Personal access token is not available and you also can't connect ADF to community edition.
You can create a trial edition on Azure/AWS which provides free DBUs. You will still need to pay for the VM and storage.
